# Per-object logging across multiple modules in Python

Tags: python, logging

I have a Python code that implements a class used to process independent data sets. For each dataset I instantiate an object from the class, which processes the data set. I would like to implement a logging feature that displays the log messages both in the console and in a log file that is stored with each data set.

I have implemented a root logger at the module level and a specific logger with a FileHandler when each of the objects is created. It works to log some of the information for what is happening inside of the class but I am also using another toolbox module and what happens there is only logged in the console but not in the log files.

To illustrate the issue I have implemented a demonstration module:

```
├──log
│  ├── __init__.py
│  ├── my_object.py
│  ├── toolbox.py
```

Content of `__init__.py`:

```py
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='%(name)12s - %(levelname)5s - %(message)s')
_log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Content of `my_object.py`:

```py
import logging
from . import toolbox

class MyObject():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name

        # configure logging
        logger = logging.getLogger(name)
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        if logger.hasHandlers():
            for hdlr in logger.handlers:
                logger.removeHandler(hdlr)

        handler = logging.FileHandler('/home/user/Desktop/test/{}.log'.format(name), mode='w', encoding='utf-8')
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)12s - %(levelname)5s - %(message)s')
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(handler)

        self._logger = logger


    def do_something(self):
        self._logger.info('{} is doing something'.format(self._name))

        toolbox.use_tool(self._name)
```

Content of `toolbox.py`:

```py
import logging

_log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def use_tool(name):
    _log.info('Using some tool for {}'.format(name))
```

Then, I run this:

```py
import log
from log.my_object import MyObject

obj = MyObject('object1')
obj.do_something()
```

And here is what I get in the console:

```
     object1 -  INFO - object1 is doing something
 log.toolbox -  INFO - Using some tool for object1
```

And here is what I get in the `/home/user/Desktop/test/object1.log` file:

```
     object1 -  INFO - object1 is doing something
```

How do I get the log.toolbox to also show up in the `object1.log` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is in how you call the `getLogger` function. There are two times you do it:

1. `logger = logging.getLogger(name)` inside `my_object.py`
2. `_log = logging.getLogger(__name__)` inside `toolbox.py`

If you compare the objects returned by those calls, these are 2 **separate** objects (you can print their addresses via `print(id(obj))`). This is why `logger` never calls the line inside the toolbox - there is a different logger (`_log`) in there!

To fix your error, simply give your loggers the same name - for example "global":

1. `logger = logging.getLogger("global")`
2. `_log = logging.getLogger("global")`

The output of the file is now as follows:

```
global -  INFO - object1 is doing something
global -  INFO - Using some tool for object1
```

In your specific example, you could adjust the code in `toolbox.py` to:

```
import logging


def use_tool(name):
    _log = logging.getLogger(name)
    _log.info('Using some tool for {}'.format(name))
```

and leave the logger inside `my_object.py` as it is (`logger = logging.getLogger(name)`). If you then do the following in `main.py`:

```
obj = MyObject('object1')
obj2 = MyObject('object2')
obj.do_something()
obj2.do_something()
```

you will end up with 2 logging files:

*object1.log*

```
object1 -  INFO - object1 is doing something
object1 -  INFO - Using some tool for object1
```

*object2.log*

```
object2 -  INFO - object2 is doing something
object2 -  INFO - Using some tool for object2
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work if `object1` and `object2` are created together and `obj1.do_something()` and `obj2.do_something()` are called afterwards. In that case `object1.log` is empty and `object2.log` contains all the logs for both objects.

Comment: That's beacuse you are using the same logger object. You need to pass the loggers around - you should get / update logger reference in `use_tool`. I will update my answer to include a more robust solution when im home later.

Comment: @Arthur I have updated my answer with a solution following your exact example.